# HTML5 Video or JavaScript variable as input to HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I already looked all around StackOverflow and Google to find a solution to this question but so far no luck.
Got a HTML page with dynamically rendered content from Django. All works good with standard text and images, however from time to time it also shows HTML5 Video element which in screenshot appears as a black image and thats it. Adding poster to it did not help. Does anyone know is it somehow possible to actually take screenshot of html5 video element? (not flash etc)
If not, my 2nd approach was to create a js variable with html content inside and then replace video with image created from poster attribute of the video. After that send that js variable to html2canvas for screenshot. Reason for this is I CAN'T alter page look and feel for user so I need to do this stuff in the background somehow. Idea was to use

```
var content = $(".content").html();
content.replace(video, image);  // pseudo here for sake of question
html2canvas(content, { ...
```

However this only keeps giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined` so that idea fails...
Does anyone know how to make this to actually work or maybe has any other idea how to replace video with image for the sake of html2canvas screenshot but with user not seeing any changes on the website?
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Hi mate, any update for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to capture html5 video element onto the "screenshot" presuming it doesn't taint the canvas (i.e. cross-origin content).

Currently, html2canvas doesn't support capturing videos nor poster images, but pull requests are always welcome.

Comment: Could you please paste me a working example of code for catching html5 video, I just tried a basic raw example of html5 video, all local (no cross origin stuff), and still video gets ignored...just something you get to work?

Comment: @MaRiNkO One example can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Manipulating_video_using_canvas